# Extracting specific file types from all tar files from specific folder

Tags: linux, shell

I need shell script which accept two arguments.
First one is path to the specific folder and second one is int value (1 or 2).

If second argument is 1 then I have to go through all tar files in mentioned folder and extract just executable files into specific folder inside path from first argument. in this case name of that folder is "unpacked".

If second argument is 2 then I have to extract all `*.txt` files from all `tar` files from folder given by first argument.

I am trying something like this but don't know how to catch every `tar` file and extract one of these two file types.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
if [$2 –eq 1 ]
then
for f in *.tar; do
tar –xv –f "$f" –-wildcards EXECUTABLE FILES -C ./unpacked
done
fi

if [$2 –eq 2 ]
then
for f in *.tar; do
tar –xv –f "$f" –-wildcards "*.txt" -C ./unpacked
done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[MEMBER...]` argument must come last.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
if [$2 –eq 1 ]
then
for f in *.tar; do
tar –xv –f "$f" –-wildcards -C ./unpacked EXECUTABLE FILES
done
fi

if [$2 –eq 2 ]
then
for f in *.tar; do
tar –xv –f "$f" –-wildcards -C ./unpacked "*.txt"
done
fi
```

Comment: it is working for txt files but for executable I have to select it somehow and don't have idea how

Comment: Unless you can identify the executables by name, then you cannot unpack only executables. You'll have to do one of the following:
1. Unpack it all and identify each file after
2. Write a program that understands tar files and can selectively pick out executables

Comment: actually second option is something what I need but not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

To Extract specific files form a tar file execute in yor terminal:

```
$ tar -zxvf TARNAME.tar.gz PATH/FILNAME
```